# dll injects only to some processes

Tags: c++, dll

I've been trying to get into making trainers for simple games, so i made dll (i know i can do it with exe but still wanted to go with dll), so i made very simple DllMain:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    std::cout << "DDDD";
    FreeConsole();
}
else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
    return 0;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

I used 3 different injectors and all seemed to inject only into few processes (counted like 4/5) and not working for others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should examine why the injection method you are using fails (e.g. whcih API call returns an error). The injection may fail because the injector process has not sufficient privileges to the target process. However, DLL injection methods may have other limitations:

- Injection via Windows Hooks takes effect only on processes running on the same desktop as the injector. Also, the DLL is injected by lazy algorithm – only in case it is required by the process (if you use a WH_GETMESSAGE hook, the target process is not injected until it gets a message). AFAIR you also need a 32-bit injector and DLL to inject into 32-bit processes and 64-bit injector and DLL to inject into 64-bit ones.
- Injection via User APC may only happen when the target thread enters a state when it is able to process pending APCs. Not all threads do that.
- The AppInit_Dlls value under the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows registry key allows you to inject your DLL into all processes that also loads user32.dll. This method seems not to work at all on Windos 8 and later versions if Secure Boot is enabled. It is also possible to configure the system in a way that only signed DLLs are loaded.
- on Vista and later, the CreateRemoteThread method may have a problem crossing session boundaries, if I remember correctly (RtlCreateUserThread should solve the problem). However, some processes may be quite unhappy (meaning they hung or crash) when you start creating user threads inside their address space.

Also, a game protection software may be blocking your injection attempts.

So, there are many possible causes to your problem. You should tell us which injection methods you tried, with what results and whether the injector process ran with administrative privileges or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not injecting a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process or vice-versa, that won't work.

Comment: No difference between 32 or 64-bit dll, still same situation.

Comment: @helloworld What do you mean not working for others? Do the injectors output some error message?